# jquery boolean iterators

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator

...or what's the proper name for `some()` and `every()`. Basically, I'm looking for a function or a plugin that would allow me to write something like:

```
okay = $("#myForm input").every(function() { 
     return $(this).val().length > 0
})
```

or

```
hasErrors = $(listOfUsers).some(function() {
   return this.errorCount > 0;
})
```

You got the idea.

(Before the what-have-you-tried squad arrives, I googled and found [jquery.arrayUtils](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.arrayUtils.js), but that code doesn't look convincing to me).

Comment: Functions of this kind are often called [aggregate functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function), because they return a single value from a list a values. Aggregate functions also include `count()`, `sum()` and `average()`, among others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple, straightforward implementation:

```
$.fn.some = function(callback) {
    var result = false;
    this.each(function(index, element) {
        // if the callback returns `true` for one element
        // the result is true and we can stop
        if(callback.call(this, index, element)) {
            result = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

$.fn.every = function(callback) {
    var result = true;
    this.each(function(index, element) {
        // if the callback returns `false` for one element
        // the result is false and we can stop
        if(!callback.call(this, index, element)) {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

---

With ES5, arrays already provide the methods [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), so you could achieve the same with built in methods:

```
okay = $("#myForm input").get().every(function(element) { 
     return $(element).val().length > 0
});
```

but it won't work in older IE version without [HTML5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/).

Comment: Simple indeed! I'd like `every` callback to receive the same arguments `each` callbacks get (i.e. index,object). Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. I updated the code. It really makes sense to provide these values to the callback (should have thought of this myself ;)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
okay = $("#myForm input").each(function() { 
     return $(this).val().length > 0
})

okay = $("#myForm input").find('class').each(function() { 
     return $(this).val().length > 0
})
```