# jQuery specify criteria for searching value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, contains

In javascript I need to know if array contains value. Values are objects and I can have different instances of same object, which means $.inArray(...) will not work. I know how to do my task using $.each(...) and my question is - is it possible to pass function with value's comparing logic to any of jQuery methods (see sample with desired sintax)?

```
    // values
var val1 = { id: 1, description: 'First value'};
var val2 = { id: 2, description: 'Second value'};
var val3 = { id: 3, description: 'Third value'};        
// array of values
var values = [ val1, val2, val3 ];
// inArray of jQuery to know if value is in array -> returns TRUE
var isInArray = $.inArray(val2, values) > -1;

// another instance of same object "val2"
var val2_anotherInstance = { id: 2, description: 'Second value'};
// inArray works as expected -> returns FALSE but desirable result is TRUE
var isInArray_anotherInstance = $.inArray(val2_anotherInstance, values) > -1;

// define function for comparing values (any logic can be implemented, for example searching by Id)
var valueComparer = function(first, second) {
    return first.id == second.id && first.description == second.description;
}
// function compares objects and returns true for different instances
alert(valueComparer(val2, val2_anotherInstance));

// desirable sintax:
// is something like this possible ???      
// NOTE next line not correct
isInArray_anotherInstance = $.inArray(val2_anotherInstance, values, valueComparer) > -1;
// actually what I want is specify criteria for searching value in array
```

Comment: Unfortunately `inArray()` doesn't take a function. You could use  `grep()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var val1 = { id: 1, description: 'First value'};
var val2 = { id: 2, description: 'Second value'};
var val3 = { id: 3, description: 'Third value'};        

var values = [ val1, val2, val3 ];

// another instance of same object "val2"
var val2_anotherInstance = { id: 2, description: 'Second value'};


var items = $.grep(values, function(x) {
    return x.id == val2_anotherInstance.id
})

var found = items.length > 0
```

For more elegance, you can use a boolean aggregator function, as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600001/989121):

```
val2_in_array = $.some(values, function() {
    return this.id == val2_anotherInstance.id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this function for your task:

```
$.fn.inArrayCallback = function(needle, haystack, f) {
  var e = -1;
  $.each(haystack,function(index, value){
      if (f(needle,value)) { e = index; return false; }
    });
  return e;
}

ans = $.fn.inArrayCallback(val2_anotherInstance, values, valueComparer) > -1; 
// returns true
```

Answer with *grep* function will search all elements in array, even if matched element is already found. This function stops searching on match. This may be significant on very big arrays.

Comment: re:your edit - that's why I also suggested `some()`, which stops as soon as the callback returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [greep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function to filter your array and then take count of the items in produced array. But it will handle all of the array and if you have a lot of data it will be not performance friendly.

Answer (score 0):

jquery map function should solve your problem.
You can implement your comparison logic in the callback of map.
[refer jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)